# jQuery UI datepicker update styles while clock running

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery ui datepicker (timer creation) along with datetimepicker customized.

I am trying to update the styles onclick of button. It is keep on resetting to default style after updating.

**Expected:**

[image]

**What I am getting:**

[image]

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4utm0ow/)**

> **HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datetimepicker"></p>
  <div id="clock"></div>
</div>    

<div class="btnHolder">
  <input type="button" value="Change font color" id="fontColor" />
  <input type="button" value="Change font size" id="fontSize" />
</div>
```

> **Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(function() {
    $( "#datetimepicker" ).datetimepicker({ 
      minDate:0,
      timeInput: true,
      timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
    });
  });

  // on changing date initilize the countdown again
  $("#datetimepicker").change(function(){
    init($(this).val());
  })

  function init(dt){
    $('#clock').countdown(dt).on('update.countdown', function(event) {
      var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
      + '<span>%-w</span> week%!w '
      +'<span>%-d</span> day%!d '
      + '<span>%H</span> hr '
      + '<span>%M</span> min '
      + '<span>%S</span> sec'));
    });
  }

  //initilize counter on load with some default date
  //init("2016/11/25");

});

jQuery(document).on('click', '#fontColor', function(){
  jQuery('#clock span').css({'color': 'red'})
})

jQuery(document).on('click', '#fontSize', function(){
  jQuery('#clock span').css({'font-size': '20px'})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the content every second with the unstyled week, days, etc. `<span>...</span>`s. So even though you set the styles correctly on the spans when you click the button, it will be replaced by the unstyled content again once every second.
You can set a class on the outer `#clock` element

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '#fontColor', function() {
  jQuery('#clock').addClass('red');
});
```

and add the following css:

```css
.red > span {
  color: red;
}
```

`>` selects the direct children of the `#clock.red` element and sets their color to red. (More about the child combinator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).)

Updated JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jcpru32t/).

Comment: **@Sebastian Richner**, thanks for the answer. But adding class does not solve my problem as user can choose color from color pallette, font family from dropdown etc...

Comment: @Reddy, in that case, you could also update the color, font, etc. within `$('#clock').countdown(dt).on('update.countdown', function(event) { ... }` based on the selected values. You could also only update the contents of each span, instead of completely replacing them, so you don't have to apply the styles/classes every second.

Comment: **@Sebastian Richner**, can you please provide fiddle as I am not able to do the same **please**?

Comment: @Reddy, sure, here's a very basic updated version of it: http://jsfiddle.net/jcpru32t/1/